# Trying to learn the facebook API but window.fbAsyncInit not being called

Tags: facebook, api

I looked but an answer to this doesn't seem to be coming up...it appears that the window.fbAsyncInit in my js file isn't being called. This is a test app to familiarize myself with the API so pretty basic and is why the PHP snippit is in the HTML portion ;). A thought I had was the JS couldn't see the fb-root DIV so I tried loading the JS after and even stripped out everything except the Facebook stuff and still nothing...neither the innerHTML for the info DIV nor the console show anything. I do get the "SDK loaded" message in the DIV and console so I know the API is loading. I'm also not getting any errors. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't working? Also tried FF, Chrome, Safari and IE (mac and pc) with the same result.
code was originally from a tutorial site (tweaked a little :) but I double checked with the facebook docs and it's identical to what he had.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guess Test</title>
    <link href="guess.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="guess.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<?php echo "Welcome to the guess test program :D<br>"; ?>

<div id="alertbox"></div>

<br>
<div>Enter your guess between 1 and 10: <input type=text id='myGuess' name='myGuess'>
<input type='button' onClick='Guess()' value='Guess'>
<br>
<br>
<input type='button' onClick='document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML = "reset"; Restart()' value='Start Again'>
<br>
<div id="info"><div>

<script type=text/javascript>Restart();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript (js file)...ID and URL removed :)

```
var iRandom;
var cheat=false;
var fb_login = "foo";
fb_login = "Start";

function Restart() {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = fb_login;
    iRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;
    if(cheat)
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = iRandom;
    var tempstring = document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML;
    if((tempstring == "") || (tempstring == "reset")) {
        document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML = "OK, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10";
        }
    }

function Guess() {
    var yourGuess = document.getElementById('myGuess').value;
    if (yourGuess>iRandom) {
        document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML = "Too High.";
        }
    if (yourGuess<iRandom) {
        document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML = "Too Low.";
        }
    if (yourGuess==iRandom) {
        document.getElementById("alertbox").innerHTML = "Well done! You guessed it.";
        Restart();
        }
    }

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    console.log("START FB init");
    fb_login = "START FB init";
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'USED-MY-APP-ID', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//MYURL.com/facebook/channel.php', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        frictionlessRequests : true // enable frictionless requests
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            fb_login = "Welcome back";
            alert("Welcome back");
            }
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //User is logged into Facebook, but not your App
            //LOG IN function
            fb_login = "App not authorized";
            alert("App not authorized");
            }
        else {
            // User is not logged into Facebook at all
            window.top.location ='https://www.facebook.com/index.php';
            fb_login = "no facebook";
            alert("no facebook");
            }
        });
    };

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    fb_login = "SDK loaded";
    console.log("SDK loaded");
    }(document));
```